# django PDF FileResponse "Failed to load PDF document."

Tags: django, pdf-generation, reportlab

I am trying to generate and output PDF from a django view. I followed the example in [django documentation using ReportLab](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/outputting-pdf/) but the downloaded PDF is not opening in any PDF readers.

I use Python 3.7.0, Django==2.1.3, reportlab==3.5.12. I tried adding `content_type="application/pdf"` to 'FileResponse` but still having the same issue.

```
import io
from django.http import FileResponse
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

def printPDF(request):
    # Create a file-like buffer to receive PDF data.
    buffer = io.BytesIO()

    # Create the PDF object, using the buffer as its "file."
    p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)


    p.drawString(100, 100, "Hello world.")


    p.showPage()
    p.save()

    return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename='hello.pdf')
```

The generated PDF should be opening in all PDF readers. But I am getting 'Failed to load PDF document.'

Answer (score 5):

`buffer = BytesIO()` is used instead of a file to store the pdf document. Before returning it with FileResponse you need to reset the stream position to its start:

```
buffer.seek(io.SEEK_SET)
```

Now the pdf download should work as expected.

Comment: Or more simply, `buffer.seek(0)`

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be something fishy going on with the interaction of `BytesIO` and `FileResponse`. The following worked for me.

```py
def printPDF(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=hello.pdf'
    p = canvas.Canvas(response)
    p.drawString(100, 100, "Hello world.")
    p.showPage()
    p.save()
    return response
```

Comment: Seems to be a  bug. I ended up using `xhtml2pdf`.

Comment: I just came across https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1126, which has been an outstanding uwsgi/Python 3/`BytesIO` bug for almost 4 years.